# Managing settings for multiple environments?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions

Azure Function Apps allows you to have a settings file such as `local.settings.json.`

You can then consume these settings like so:

```
[FunctionName("CustomSettings")]
public static Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "GET")]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info("101 Azure Function Demo - Accessing Environment variables");
    var customSetting =  Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CustomSetting", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
    return Task.FromResult(req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { setting= customSetting }));
}
```

This is well and good; however, the challenge becomes apparent when needing to manage settings for multiple environments, analogous to config transforms.

**How do we manage app settings across multiple environments?**

For example, if I deploy from dev to main, how do I retrieve the settings for the main environment?

Comment: perhaps this is a deploy-time responsibility?

Comment: I think as Alex mentioned , it sounds deployment time. Maybe through Arm Template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetEnvironmentVariable` is good enough to retrieve settings in `Values` of local.settings.json and also Application settings on Azure. We only need to make sure those settings have been configured locally or on Azure portal.

Generally there might be two configurations:

**We Don't want to mix development configuration with production environment**

1. One common and easy way is to visit portal to edit Application settings.
2. For VS deployment, we can Manage Application settings during deployment. If we want to modify settings before deployment, just choose `create profile` instead of `publish` and publish after editing application settings.

   [image: application settings in VS]
3. If we choose Continuous Delivery like VSTS, we can also manage application settings with [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/functionapp/config/appsettings?view=azure-cli-latest) or [related extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AjeetChouksey.appsettings#overview) in build and release pipeline.
4. [ARM template](http://mlogdberg.com/azurefunctions/arm-manage-application-settings) is also recommended if we have to change the settings frequently.

**We want to synchronize local dev settings to production env**

1. Use [Azure function core tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local#v2).

   After installation, in cmd(or powershell, bash, etc.) navigate to your function app directory(where local.settings.json locates). Use following command to get appsettings from Azure to local.setting.json and to publish those settings to Azure. (Note that fetch-app-settings also retrieves Connection settings on Azure, but publish only updates Application settings.)

   ```
   func azure functionapp fetch-app-settings <functionappname>
   func azure functionapp publish <functionappname> --publish-settings-only
   ```

   If we want to use this cli in VSTS, note that `local.setting.json` need to be committed to repository(by editing gitignore) because usually it's not. We should set a npm task to install function cli first as by default it's not installed on the infrastructure, then add another task to run the command.
2. For [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/tutorials/functions-extension/getting-started) users, it's just a simple click.
   [image]

Pay attention to the overwrite prompt when using cli and VS Code, make sure dev settings won't cover useful ones on other environment.

**Explanation**

1. Editing portal application settings is truly manual, but for those who develop online or those who don't need to modify their settings frequently, modification on portal can be a reasonable option.
2. Some [Application settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings) are only useful on Azure. Similarly, not every value works in [local.setting.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local#local-settings-file) is valid on Azure. **So by design Azure doesn't merge these two part settings together**. Of course our custom settings can be read with `GetEnvironmentVariable` in both local and Azure env once set correctly.

Comment: thank you very much. regarding _One common and easy way is to visit portal to edit Application settings_ -- i dont believe that this is an option. this process is too manual.

Comment: your _create profile_ idea looks very cool; however, is it possible to create a _local_ profile? if i want to test locally, how do i use the appsettings? i understand that when we deploy remotely, we can set the app settings for every profile, but **are the appsettings available during debug time in VS**?

Comment: @AlexGordon Sorry that my words got you confused. See my update.

Comment: thanks so much. so how would this look like within our deployment process? let's say we are deploying fom VSTS, would we run the `func azure functionapp publish <functionappname> --publish-settings-only` command?

Comment: @AlexGordon For this purpose `local.setting.json` need to be committed to repository(edit gitignore) because usually it's not. We should set a npm task `npm install -g azure-fucntions-core-tools` first as by default function cli is not installed on the infrastructure, then add another task to run the command.